# Is it important to read the theory behind mathematical optimization in order to solve practical problems?

Tags: optimization, soft-question

Sorry if this question seems a little bit vague.

I'm starting to study about optimization and I'm interested in the applications to practical problems.

Since nowadays computer programs can handle pretty well with a lot of optimization problems (LP, NLP,...), is it important to study deeply the theory behind it? I've seen books using tools like analysis, topology, etc. and I don't know if I need to study them now in order to solve big and interesting problems in the industry in the near future. I'm pretty confused, I can read these books I have a good background in mathematics but I don't know if it's essential now.

Comment: The more you understand the mathematics behind it, the better you will be able to use the algorithms and change them when things go awry.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip could you give me a practical example?

Comment: Well as a practical matter, basic linear programming and more advanced nonlinear optimization depends a lot on thresholds. Theoretically something works if some value is 0, but then when you run the algorithm it fails because the value was $10^{-6}$. Understanding the math behind the algorithm can help you determine what might be going wrong, how to recast the problem to be less sensitive, or to adjust the thresholds accordingly.

Comment: To follow up on what Cheerful Parship said ( which I totally agree with ), it is also helpful to understand the theory so that you can know which method is best suited for each problem. There can be cases where two different methods will lead to an answer but one might be a lot more efficient than the other because of the structure of the problem.  Also, there was a case where a buggy optimization algorithm was resulting in answers for many years and no one knew that the fortran algorithm used had a bug in it.  Without knowledge of the theory, it would be basically impossible to find that bug.

Comment: @markleeds could you suggest a theoretical book about this subject?

Comment: that's a hard question. it depends if you want discussion of a specific algorithm or a more general viewpoint. boyd is good. So is bazarra and shetty. both are more general. There are so many.  I have some in the garage so let me look tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @markleeds thank you

Comment: Hi: I looked in the garage. nocedal and wright has a lot of coverage on the various algorithms. That's quite a popular one that I forgot about.   bertsekas has a good reputation so my guess is that his non-linear programming would be interesting.  For kinder and gentler texts ( not as difficult and coverage is less ), check out perressini's yellow book and aoki's optimization text.

Comment: @markleeds thank you very much, what is the name of Bertsekas book?

Comment: Hi: non-linear programming.